# Scraping using selenium and scrapy return none

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping using selenium and scrapy. Scrapy only because selenium was failing to return values, but scrapy is also returning none.
Essentially not able to get the dropdown values and the table values from the site. Is the website content locked or something else is wrong? i can see the option values in returned page source but selenium or scrapy are not able to pick them up. Currently hardcoded a dropdown option to view the table

```
class CanaraBankSpider(scrapy.Spider):
"""This class defines Canara Bank Spider."""

name = "canara_bank_ins"
URL = "https://canarabank.com/locator.aspx"

start_urls = (URL,)
brand_name = "Canara Bank"
spider_type = "chain"

def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://canarabank.com/locator.aspx")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (
                By.XPATH,
                "//select[@name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddllocater']/option[text()='Branch Details']",
            )
        )
    ).click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (
                By.XPATH,
                "//select[@name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlstate']/option[text()='Bihar']",
            )
        )
    ).click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (
                By.XPATH,
                "//select[@name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddldistrict']/option[text()='Gaya']",
            )
        )
    ).click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (
                By.NAME,
                "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnview",
            )
        )
    ).click()
    selector = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
    print(
        selector.xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvlocatordata"]//tr[2]/td[3]')
    )
```

Any help is hugely appreciated

Comment: Sorry for that I'm not understanding  what's your desired output  and what are the  prerequisites meaning what's things to do please explain a bit clearly, explain about : brand_name = "Canara Bank"  
spider_type = "chain"

Comment: so those two fields are meta data. basically I wanted to scrape the data like address and phone number regarding all the branches of this bank. so for that I need to scrape the tables, butt searching by XPath and all is returning null

Comment: also wanted to gett dropdown value options to make a for loop for all states/cities